# Displaying Usernames Name after Login

Tags: php

recently I am coming up with a lot of problems, one I cant seem to figure out at the moment is the displaying of a username's name after he logged in. This is the code I have at the moment:

```
$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_username'])) {
  $colname_Recordset1 = $_SESSION['MM_username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_login, $login);
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT Name FROM `Start-Login` WHERE Email = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset1, "text"));
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $login) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
```

And further down the page I have my output:

```
echo $row_Recordset1['Name'];
```

However, after the user successfully logged in, it will not display the name of the user.

I am looking forward to your answer, thanks,
Jan

Comment: What exactly does `GetSQLValueString()` do ? It's not a core php function.

Comment: It is a function Dreamweaver created for me further up the page. I tried putting it in here, but it does not allow that many characters

Comment: Unless `GetSQLValueString()` adds quotes you need to have them in your SQL code: `WHERE Email = '%s'`. Also note that this is d* open to SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

The code I provided above was actually correct, I just had to change the lowercase "u" in MM_username to an uppercase U.